# Pandas nunique() for categorical columns only, null otherwise?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I want to check the number of unique values for categorical columns in a dataframe. df.nunique() gives me unique values for all columns, which takes a long time. To make it faster, I want to skip over anything that's a numberical column. However, I  still want the output to be the full series containing all columns, just with Nulls for numerical columns (and without computing these columns).

I've been playing around with df._get_numeric_data(), sets and df.unquniue() but haven't gotten to the output I want yet.

So input

```
col_name type
col1    object
col2    object
col3    float64
col4    float64
col5    float64
col6    object
col7    float64
col8    object
col9    object
```

Desired output:

```
col_name    nunqiue
col1    23
col2    3
col3    null
col4    null
col5    null
col6    4
col7    null
col8    6
col9    2
```

The key here is to save the computational work from computing unique values of a float, and do this in a streamlined pandaish way...

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't the `dtype` be `category` if they are categorical columns? Seems you have just strings...

Comment: You are correct, I need to set those to category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***MCVE***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
       np.random.randint(1, 100, (100, 9)), columns=[f'col{i}' for i in range(1, 10)])

df[['col1', 'col2', 'col6', 'col8', 'col9']] = \
    df[['col1', 'col2', 'col6', 'col8', 'col9']].astype(object)

>>> df.dtypes
col1    object
col2    object
col3     int32
col4     int32
col5     int32
col6    object
col7     int32
col8    object
col9    object
dtype: object
```

---

You can use the `exclude` argument of [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to exclude all numeric columns from your calculation.

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').nunique().reindex(df.columns)
```

```
col1    62.0
col2    63.0
col3     NaN
col4     NaN
col5     NaN
col6    63.0
col7     NaN
col8    65.0
col9    61.0
dtype: float64
```

---

You can fiddle around with both the `include` and `exclude` parameters to `select_dtypes` to match exactly the columns you want to include.